# Good book on Combinatorics w\ solved problems

Tags: combinatorics, book-recommendation

What is the best book to learn Combinatorics from scratch w\ a lot of solved exercises?

I can do calculus, derivates, integrals but i for me Combinatorics is VERY hard because I do not know how to approaches to the problems.

I found Oscar Levin's book but it not the type of book I am looking for. I want to practice with exercises because it seem the only way to master this subject!

Comment: I Like this https://d1wqtxts1xzle7.cloudfront.net/59656181/ec120190610-6957-cp1g77.pdf?1560217042=&response-content-disposition=inline%3B+filename%3DEnumerative_Combinatorics_Volume_1_secon.pdf&Expires=1609584495&Signature=Q4Xi1s1EsN1X-g5fyvPVrznq4EPe6Br4X8CuxU-M7ZhlcX-s1c8Ti1pq8IewEGugDRMETqiATUDkEgIyx-qej8NNmjwxdUS8WPKpJ9n0BDsF9unwK6bg6upTgRX4Jw9vRDBDH6k5a058tswBGD6giKR0y8RBnRZ7hDnX5Xd2GjMD8x5c2XafmAYe8Zd0v8Txsoq1bALbMsJQeNaHrHvbvoeJZaZrV4GgIQotk11TCymrsWVzRgMtNjvg0yRbd2lBOxPNrPERUNEA6SFONwTGmG0si0VVMA5ZdY-H5-tkV7mme6Z7R349ojooRXh2ViiuUBpgiSFJsYli3C23KDLwzQ__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLOHF5GGSLRBV4ZA

Comment: Try [Principles and Techniques of Combinatorics](https://www.amazon.com/Principles-Techniques-Combinatorics-KHEE-MENG-KOH/dp/9810211392/ref=sr_1_4?crid=16NLZE3Y6G95J&dchild=1&keywords=combinatorics&qid=1609581140&s=books&sprefix=Combinatorics%2Caps%2C183&sr=1-4) by Chen and Koh.

Comment: For Richard Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics, see here: http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ec1/

Comment: I'm fond of John Riordan's *[Introduction to Combinatorial Analysis](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Combinatorial-Analysis-Dover-Mathematics/dp/0486425363)*. A lot of exercises, but no solution. For a book with problems *and* solutions, have a look to *[Combinatorics
A Problem-Based Approach](https://www.amazon.com/Combinatorics-Problem-Approach-Pavle-Mladenovic/dp/3030008304)* by Pavle Mladenović.

Comment: See also *[Combinatorics: A Problem Oriented Approach](https://www.amazon.com/Combinatorics-Oriented-Mathematical-Association-Textbooks/dp/0883857103)* by Daniel Marcus, and a review by the MAA:.https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/combinatorics-a-problem-oriented-approach

Comment: The Schaum's Outline consists almost entirely of worked exercises.  *Schaum's Theory and Problems of Combinatorics* by V.K. Balakrishnan.

Comment: You could do a lot worse than Miklós Bóna, [*A Walk Through Combinatorics: An Introduction to Enumeration and Graph Theory*](https://books.google.com/books/about/Walk_Through_Combinatorics_A_An_Introduc.html?id=uZRIDQAAQBAJ).